# Calculus 2 - Hydrostatic Force (having trouble understanding distance)

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

Here's a picture someone drew over from Slader.
[image: pic] 
https://d37b4ew8393wk3.cloudfront.net/16/07/16/c60daaa3e9fb08969e7adee9caa119f9/11f3a4812b10dc3600c6d994a5e6d74c/image_scan.JPG

Can someone break down how he got distance is $12-y$? Isn't $12-y$ just covering the distance up until $(0,0)$, not the whole circle?

For my work I've gotten:

1. $\Delta A = 2 * \sqrt{64-x^2} (m^2)$
2. $\Delta P = 1000(kg/m^3)*9.8(m/s^2)*d(12-y?)$
3. $\Delta F = \Delta A * \Delta P$

If someone could break it down for me that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Under $y=0$ you have $y<0$ and $d>12$, so all equations hold.

Answer (score 1):

The line with coordinates $y=0$ has the distance
$8 + 4 = 12$
to the surface, so the distance of something with coordinate $y$ to the surface is $d(y) = 12 - y$. It fits $d(0) = 12$ and $d(12) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the distance from $y = 0$ to the surface as $d$,the distance from $y=0$ to the strip as $y$ and the distance from the strip to the surface as $y_1$ then $d = y+y_1$ i.e $d-y = y_1 \Rightarrow 12-y = y_1$.

Comment: This distance is just for rectangles  above $y = 0$ isn't it? What about for stuff under $y=0$?

Comment: What is the whole problem asking? Can you give me the statement?

Comment: A vertical plate is submerged (or partially submerged) in
water and has the indicated shape. Explain how to approximate the
hydrostatic force against one side of the plate by a Riemann sum.
Then express the force as an integral and evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most straightforward. Total distance center to surface is 12. Take away center to strip  $y$, leaving $12-y$ strip to surface.